# get all nested children for a parent id

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

[Started Fiddling](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/43b34/3)

```
Work Table
ProductId, LabelName, CategoryId, ChildCategoryId
------------------------------------
1, Widget A, 1, null
null, Category A, 2, 1 
2, Widget B, 3, null

Categories Table
CategoryId, CategoryName
---------------------------
1, Category A
2, Category B
3, Category C
```

Given the information above, how would you get all categories for a product id?

For example, given a product id of 1, the following would be the desired results.

```
Desired Results
ProductId, LabelName, CategoryId, ChildCategoryId
------------------------------------
1, Widget A, 1, null
null, Category A, 2, 1 
null, Category B, null, 2
```

It is supposed to be hierarchical data and I apologize for not being able to explain very well. It is just boggling my mind. Widget A has a product id of 1 and category id of 1. This means all records that have a ChildCategoryId of 1 is included, which gives us Category A. CatA has a category id of 2, so like before, all records that have a ChildCategoryId of 2 is included in result, which is why Category B is included.

Comment: Can you explain how you arrive at the desired results from the sample data you've provided? And where does `associationTable` come in?

Comment: I renamed association table to Transaction Table to be a little more clear. May not have worked. It's not a master table or a join table. It's like a results table I guess.

Comment: Category B is related to Widget A through Category A. The 2nd record in the Transaction table shows that Category A has a category id of 2 assigned to it.

Comment: I'm still not getting it. Your comment says "Category A has a category id of 2". `Categories` says 'Category A' has a `CategoryId` of 1. `TransactionTable` happens to have a row with `LabelName` 'Category A' (Previously 'Category 1'.) and `CategoryId` of 2, but it is not, apparently, related in any way to the 'Widget A' row. You're not assuming that the order of the rows in the table is significant, are you? If so, you'll need to provide an explicit order. Can you edit your question to include a simple step-by-step procedure? That would make writing a CTE much easier.

Comment: Order of rows is not significant. This is the confusing part I was talking about. In TransactionTable, the 2nd record, it says Category A, however, the category id refers to child record linked to it. Let me try to rephrase OP somehow

Comment: Why isn't the hierarchy of categories stored in the `Categories` table? *That's* what was most confusing for me at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This mess produces the sample result from the sample data. It still isn't clear what *you* think the algorithm ought to be.

```
declare @CategoryItems as Table (
  CategoryName NVarChar(255),
  Label NVarChar(255),
  ProductId Int,
  ChildCategoryId Int,
  CategoryId Int );

declare @Categories as Table (
  CategoryId Int,
  Name NVarChar(100) );

insert into @CategoryItems ( CategoryName, Label, ProductId, ChildCategoryId, CategoryId ) values
  ( 'CategoryA', 'Widget A', 1, 0, 1 ),
  ( 'CategoryB', 'CategoryA', 0, 1, 2 ),
  ( 'CategoryC', 'Widget B', 2, 0, 3 );
insert into @Categories ( CategoryId, Name ) values
  ( 1, 'CategoryA' ),
  ( 2, 'CategoryB' ),
  ( 3, 'CategoryC' );

select * from @Categories;
select * from @CategoryItems;

declare @TargetProductId as Int = 1;

with Leonard as (
  -- Start with the target product.
  select 1 as [Row], ProductId, Label, CategoryId, ChildCategoryId
    from @CategoryItems
    where ProductId = @TargetProductId
  union all
  -- Add each level of child category.
  select L.Row + 1, NULL, CI.Label, CI.CategoryId, CI.ChildCategoryId
    from @CategoryItems as CI inner join
      Leonard as L on L.CategoryId = CI.ChildCategoryId ),
  Gertrude as (
    -- Take everything that makes sense.
    select Row, ProductId, Label, CategoryId, ChildCategoryId
      from Leonard
    union
    -- Then tack on an extra row for good measure.
    select L.Row + 1, NULL, C.Name, NULL, C.CategoryId
      from Leonard as L inner join
        @Categories as C on C.CategoryId = L.CategoryId
      where L.Row = ( select Max( Row ) from Leonard ) )
  select Row, ProductId, Label, CategoryId, ChildCategoryId
    from Gertrude
    order by Row;
```

I suspect that the problem is that you have mixed your data in a lopsided manner. A hierarchy of categories is usally represented something like:

```
declare @Categories as Table (
  CategoryId Int Identity,
  Category NVarChar(128),
  ParentCategoryId Int Null );
```

The root of each hierarchy is indicated by `ParentCategoryId is NULL`. This allows any number of independent trees to coexist in a single table and does not depend on the existence of any products.

If products are assigned to a single (sub)category then just include the `CategoryId` in the `Products` table. If a product may be assigned to several (sub)categories, possibly in different hierarchies, then use a separate table to relate them:

```
declare @ProductCategories as Table (
  ProductId Int,
  CategoryId Int );
```

Comment: Anyone know of a resource link or example non-cte recursive SQL query

Comment: @Rod - AFAIK, the only way to implement a _recursive query_ in TSQL is with a CTE. You can implement _recursion_ using a loop and temporary table(s), cursors optional, or possibly with a table-valued function. Why do you ask?