# Single query to return nested hierarchy rows

Tags: sql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

```
+----+----------+-------+
| Id | ParentId | Value |
+----+----------+-------+
|  1 |        0 | X     |
|  2 |        1 | X     |
|  3 |        1 | X     |
|  4 |        2 | X     |
+----+----------+-------+
```

I have a database like this, the restriction is:

- A row will be child of at most 1 other row
- A row can have many child rows
- There can be more nested levels

The query I want to do is getting all rows linked to row with id=1. So I need to return all rows in the correct hierarchy.
I'm wondering if there's a single query that can help me achive this? I'm aware that using loops is possible, but it will slow down a lot.
If you have any suggestions of a better way to structure this, please let me know. I'm not restricted to modification of the whole database.

Comment: Do you need to update the data hierarchy often? If not, you may want to consider the nested set model instead.

Comment: Write a function getRootId(Id): case when Id's ParentId = 0 (or whatever your base case is) then Id, else getRootId(Id's ParentId). This function can be highly optimized with a *RootId already found* short circuit if you are writing result to a column. Process on an ordered basis. This could even be built into a table trigger. The result would be a new column, rootId, that always has the Id at the very bottom of any record's hierarchy.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18601916/get-all-nested-children-for-a-parent-id

Comment: Tag your DB. SQL is just a language, each DB has different supported functions  and syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which database product you are using, but the following is ANSI standard SQL (and supported by all modern DBMS):

```
with recursive tree as (
   select id, parentid, value
   from the_table
   where id = 1
   union all
   select ch.id, ch.parentid, ch.value
   from the_table ch
     join tree p on p.id = ch.parentid
)
select * 
from tree;
```